# not able to get value from req.body in node.js

Tags: node.js

Being a beginner i m trying to develop a very simple service using express in node js the aim of my service is that a simple index page taking a value and after submit it show on next page.This is mine code in app.js. i am not able to get value of text box by req.body. when i print req.body.response in console is shows undefined.any help will be appreciated.

```
var http = require('http'); //used for http request
var express = require('express'); //express
var session = require('express-session'); //used for creating session

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var errorHandler = require('errorhandler'); //used for error handling
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'); //used for creation of cookies
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session); //mongo
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

app.set('views/index', path.join(__dirname, 'views/index'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// build mongo database connection url //

var dbHost = process.env.DB_HOST || 'localhost'
var dbPort = process.env.DB_PORT || 27017;
var dbName = process.env.DB_NAME || 'demo';

var dbURL = 'mongodb://'+dbHost+':'+dbPort+'/'+dbName;

var data = '';

var response;
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.title);
    response = {
        email:req.body.email,
        password:req.body.password
    };
    console.log(response);
    res.render('index', {  title: 'index' });

});

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

//code for jade

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title home
  body
    form(method='get')
      .col-lg-12
        .col-lg-6
          label name
        .col-lg-6
          input(type='text', name='name')
      .col-lg-12
        .col-lg-6
          label email
        .col-lg-6
          input(type='email', name='email')
      .col-lg-12
        .col-lg-6
          label Password
        .col-lg-6
          input(type='password', name='password')
      .col-lg-12
        input(type='submit', name='submit', value='Save')
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to send data, your form needs to `POST`, not `GET`.

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title home
  body
    form(method='post', action='/')
      .col-lg-12
        .col-lg-6
          label name
        .col-lg-6
          input(type='text', name='name')
      .col-lg-12
        .col-lg-6
          label email
        .col-lg-6
          input(type='email', name='email')
      .col-lg-12
        .col-lg-6
          label Password
        .col-lg-6
          input(type='password', name='password')
      .col-lg-12
        input(type='submit', name='submit', value='Save')
```

You will then have `req.body.name`, `req.body.email` and `req.body.password` available in your application. You are not submitting anything called `title`, hence `req.body.title = undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Please check express docs:

- [req.body](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body)
- [req.query](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query)

If you submit your data via GET Query string, then express will provide those parameters already parsed as properties of the `req.query` object, not `req.body`